# List of Endpoints or URIs for a WCF client test-drive

Tags: .net, wcf, rest, uri, wcf-client

I am aware of the Amazon.com exposed URIs  ... which I need to sign up for and then on I can utilize them .......  roll-up my sleeves ..... and get some WCF Client test-drive coding.

What are the other such publicly exposed end points that reflect real or almost real-time services?

Any offerings specifically from Microsoft?

I am basically looking for writing WCF clients for both WCF and non-WCF services...RESTful ones and even otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For one, you can check out the "Visit MIX" API - an OData service (WCF Data Service):

```
http://api.visitmix.com/OData.svc/
```

Go to http://www.odata.org - there's a whole bunch of other API's published there.

Should get you started! Otherwise - just build your own! Create your own test server (that'll be a good learning experience, too!) and then connect to it.

For SOAP / classic web services go check out http://www.xmethods.net - it has a repository of a bunch of publicly available web services - everything from weather, to currency converters, to whatever you can dream up. Those give you samples for SOAP based WCF service clients.